# How Do I Force Ansible To Always Run A Task

Tags: ansible

I have a task that shuts down any running processes using my application files and it is called twice in the deployment from different roles.
The problem is that in between the two roles someone starts a new process.
Ansible skips the second stop task because it thinks the `"Conditional result was False"`
This then causes the deployment to fail.

How can I force ansible to not check and always run the task?
It is at a task level and not a role level so I can't use `always`.

Comment: do some trick using `or` operator in when condition. Eg: `when: False or ( variable is set during 1st run is defined)`.

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I force Ansible to not check and always run the task?*

Depending on the tasks (annot. which are not given or described in your question), to do so you may need to set

```yaml
when: true
check_mode: false
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Basic conditionals with `when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when)
- [Enforcing or preventing check mode on tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks)
- [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure)